# OpenCV 2.4.4 wth CUDA: registerPageLocked fails

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu

I am trying to page-lock a Mat that has already been created.
Consider the following example code:

```
...
Mat cpuGray;
GpuMat gpuGray;
cv::cvtColor (cpuColor, cpuGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
registerPageLocked(cpuGray);
gpuStream.enqueueUpload(cpuGray, gpuGray);
...
```

At runtime this fails with:

```
OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (invalid argument) in registerPageLocked, file ../gpu/src/matrix_operations.cpp, line 194
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  ../gpu/src/matrix_operations.cpp:194: error: (-217) invalid argument in function registerPageLocked
Aborted
```

Does anyone know what I am doing to cause this error?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think your `cpuGray` might be an empty matrix. The function `registerPageLocked(cpuGray)` needs to know how much memory needs to be page-locked for `cpuGray`. Make sure that `cpuGray` is not an empty matrix. `cpuGray` is initialized in

```
cv::cvtColor (cpuColor, cpuGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

so make sure that `cpuColor` is not empty.

Comment: Thank you Alex, but I thought of that too -- now I probe gpuGray for its size and pointer before calling registerPageLocked.

Comment: No, it still fails with the same error, even though the input Mat is valid and not empty.